# AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'index' is read-only

Tags: python, tensorflow, socketserver

I am new in python programing. I try to connect tensorflow with MT4 data. I use a working solution to transfer data but have some problet to add it to tensorflow. I try to use the basic timeseries prediction.

```
def train_test_model(msg=''):
   msg = msg.replace('true', 'True')
   msg = ast.literal_eval(msg)

   print(type(msg))

   if (type(msg) == dict):
    input_data = msg
   else:
    return "BAD JSON!!"

   uni_data = input_data['Data']
   uni_data.index = input_data['Time']

   uni_data = uni_data.values

   uni_train_mean = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean()
   uni_train_std = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std()

   uni_data = (uni_data - uni_train_mean) / uni_train_std
```

what I get: 
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'index' is read-only

Thisis the socket server which get the data:

```
class socketserver:
    def __init__(self, address='', port=9090):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.sock.bind((self.address, self.port))
        self.cummdata = ''

    def recvmsg(self):
        self.sock.listen(1)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('connected to', self.addr)
        self.cummdata = ''

        while True:
            data = self.conn.recv(10000000)
            self.cummdata += data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                break
            self.conn.send(bytes(train_test_model(self.cummdata), "utf-8"))

            return self.cummdata
```

Comment: You can't assign any value to read-only attributes of objects. And `index` is a `read-only` attribute of `list`. What are you trying to do with `uni_data.index = input_data['Time']` line ? Maybe you wanted `uni_data` to be a `pandas` dataframe ? If yes, then fix the line with `uni_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data['Data'])` and don't forget to `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign any value to read-only attributes of objects. And `index` is a `read-only` attribute of `list`. What are you trying to do with `uni_data.index = input_data['Time']` line ? Maybe you wanted `uni_data` to be a `pandas` dataframe ? If yes, then fix the line with `uni_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data['Data'])` and don't forget to `import pandas as pd`.

*Credit han solo*